# RAID5 reconfiguration with global hotsphere on HP 4200 with Smart Array P840ar Controller

Tags: raid, glusterfs

I have three HP 4200 server with 28 LFF disks, currently it is in RAID5 but no hotsphere, only one disk is outside the
RAID configuration. We are planning to reconfiure it with 24 disks in RAID5 with 4 disks as global hotsphere. We have GlusterFS in it.
Please advise the best procedure for the same. or if there's any better ways than this.
Also is there a way I can do it without loosing all my data.
HPE Smart Array P840ar Controller

Thanks for your time. 
RK

Answer (score 0):

this activity has been completed. We have created 3*8 disks arrays (4TB/disk) in RAID5 and used 4 spare disks to cater for all 3 arrays as global hot spare. It will allow to choose the same disk as hot spare disks for multiple arrays. Thanks.